# Flutter doesn't work on VS CODE Chrome browser. Shows error

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome, debugging, vscode-debugger

I have been using chrome to debug my flutter apps since it's way faster and consumes less RAM for me. My system hangs when I connect the phone and use it. Anyways, so recently when I opened chrome it started going to localhost:8080 by default and won't start my app. On top of that, I got errors like

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to delete the launch.json file in your directory and start debugging again. Now my app runs fine again on port 45819.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Delete the `launch.json` file in your directory and run with debugging again.

**Solution 2:**
Open vs code terminal. And run command bellow:

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get 
flutter run -d chrome // If chrome is available in your machine
```

Otherwise run command bellow:

```
flutter run
```

then chose device option for run app.

**Solution 3:**

If your project exist like - demo_folder> demo_project

Don't open demo_folder directly.

Go to demo_folder then go to demo_project then open vs code